# Python script never run from batch file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

Hi guys I have trouble running a python script from a batch file.
Its an automated routine who's suppose to create a .txt file with the output of a cmd and format it into a tabbed .txt file. It a really simple script but I'm kinda bad with Windows. 
Here's the script:

```
fmsadmin list clients -s -u user -p pass > C:\fmsadminLogs\report.txt
C:\python27\python.exe C:\fmsadminLogs\formatPowershellToTAB.py %* C:\fmsadminLogs\report.txt
del report.txt
```

When I perform it on OSX it works like a charm but on windows server 2012 R2 it just create the report.txt file and never format it with the script I tried to run it as administrator but I still only get the unmodified document. 
I tried different syntax for the python script step such as:

```
C:\python27\python.exe C:\fmsadminLogs\formatPowershellToTAB.py %* report.txt
C:\python27\python.exe C:\fmsadminLogs\formatPowershellToTAB.py report.txt
C:\python27\python.exe C:\fmsadminLogs\formatPowershellToTAB.py %1 report.txt
```

But none worked so I ask you guys!
Many thanks

Comment: How does the script read the txt file?  Does it open the filename from args[] or does it read stdin?

Comment: I use argv to open the file

Comment: Why are you passing `%*`?  That is usually used to substitute parameters.  So the second one should work, but you are deleting `report.txt` straight after running the script.

Comment: I used `%*` because i saw that syntax in some posts and It was worth trying, I know I delete the report but my script create a new file with a timestamp anyway so I don't really need it. At the moment the script doesn't even go to that step it just runs the first command and create the report.txt

Comment: I suspect your program is making the output you want, but is putting it in a location you did not intend.

Comment: I found some file with the right name in the C:\Windows\System32 folder but they are empty and the name cuts at the end "report_2016-09-16_16" instead of "report_2016-09-16_16-15.txt", when I run it on OSX it does create the file in the folder of the script. I don't understand why a python script would run differently on windows than on mac

Comment: When you run as administrator, the working directory is `%SystemRoot%\System32`. The script folder is `script_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))`. You could use `infile_name, infile_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(infile));` `outfile = os.path.join(script_dir, '%s_%s%s' % (infile_name, timestamp, infile_ext))`.